# Print from Mac OS X pointing to a compatible windows machine

Tags: windows, printer, osx-leopard

HI, I need to print to a printer which is only supported in windows. I use Mac OS X Leopard.

I can install window drivers in another machine at the office and everything works ok. I wonder if somehow, windows can share this printer access, so from Mac OS X I can print, pointing to the windows machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

If you configure the printer on Windows to be shared, then your Mac should see the printer on your network (assuming the windows machine is awake and online on the same LAN).

You can also look at [PrintFab](http://www.printfab.net/). This is a Mac application which provides drivers for [many printers](http://www.printfab.net/printers.html) without native Mac drivers.

Comment: thanks a lot for the link. unfortunately the printer is OKI and there is no support there